# Python/Pandas – Como criar um data frame que contenha a linha original e a linha duplicada

Tags: python, pandas

Em um data frame que contem duas linhas com o Pais = Índia, consegui criar
um data frame sem duplicidade com somente uma linha da Índia 
Um data frame somente com a linha duplicada
Preciso criar um data frame que contenha somente as duas linhas do País = Índia
Como posso fazer isso?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
'País': ['Bélgica', 'Índia', 'Brasil','Índia'],
'Capital': ['Bruxelas', 'Nova Delhi', 'Brasília', 'Nova Delhi'],
'População': [123465, 456789, 987654, 456789]
}
# gera DF excluindo as linhas duplicadas
drop_df = df.drop_duplicates()
# gera data frame somente com as duplicidades 
dfdrop = df[df.duplicated() == True]
```

Como gerar um DF somente com as duas linhas do País Índia???

Answer (score 2):

([TL;DR](https://anaconda.org/sidon/pandas_duplicated/notebook))
 
**Construindo o dataframe a partir dos dados:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
data = OrderedDict(
{
'País': ['Bélgica', 'Índia', 'Brasil','Índia'],
'Capital': ['Bruxelas', 'Nova Delhi', 'Brasília', 'Nova Delhi'],
'População': [123465, 456789, 987654, 456789]
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Apresentando o dataframe original:**

```
df
```

**Output:**

[image: Dataframe original]

**Expurgando os duplicados:**

```
df_clean = df.drop_duplicates()
df_clean
```

**output:**

[image: Dataframe sem duplicidades]

**Selecionando os duplicados:**

```
paises = df.País
df_duplicates = df[paises.isin(paises[paises.duplicated()])]
df_duplicates
```

**Output:**

[image: Dataframe somente com os duplicados]

[Veja o código rodando em um jupyter notebook.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/pandas_duplicated/notebook)

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando o comando duplicated, ele possui o parâmetro keep
keep - last marca somente a segunda como duplicado  (default)
     = first marca somente a primeira
     = False marca as duas
Então para cria o dataframe com as linhas duplicadas basta executar o comando:
dfdrop = df[df.duplicated('País', keep=False) == True]